# Convert Compound Primary Key to Single Column Key with Multiple Attribute Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot, denormalization

I have a set of data in a table with a compound primary key, but the reason for the second column in the key is pretty spurious for our uses and I need to convert the table to one with a single column primary key and a single main attribute, with some additional optional attribute fields in place of the previously spurious rows, in case they are ever needed for reference. Here is an example:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Input') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Input;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Output') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Output;

CREATE TABLE #Input
( Id    INT         NOT NULL
 ,Attribute NVARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT OriginalName PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id, Attribute));
CREATE TABLE #Output
( Id            INT         NOT NULL
 ,Attribute1    NVARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
 ,Attribute2    NVARCHAR(1)     NULL
 ,Attribute3    NVARCHAR(1)     NULL
CONSTRAINT hmmAnotherOriginalName PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id));

INSERT #Input(Id,Attribute)
    SELECT 1,1 UNION
    SELECT 2,2 UNION
    SELECT 2,3 UNION
    SELECT 2,1 UNION
    SELECT 3,3 UNION
    SELECT 4,5 UNION
    SELECT 4,1

INSERT #Output(Id,Attribute1,Attribute2,Attribute3)
    SELECT 1,   1,  NULL,   NULL    UNION
    SELECT 2,   1,  2,      3       UNION
    SELECT 3,   3,  NULL,   NULL    UNION
    SELECT 4,   1,  5,      NULL

SELECT * FROM #Input
SELECT * FROM #Output

DROP TABLE #Output
DROP TABLE #Input
```

I have tried a few PIVOTs, but the problem I have is that although I know there is a maximum number of attributes (3 in the example), I have no idea what the actual values of the attributes are (in the real case, they are actually alternative spellings of state names). All the stuff with dynamic column names hasn't helped me so far; since a state name could appear in any of the attribute columns, it all gets a bit confused.

I tried grouping my input on Id, listing only those having more than one attribute, then making a dynamic list of those attributes and pivoting them, but again, it led me to a dead end.

I don't actually care which of the available attributes for any one id is listed as the "main", non-nullable attribute column, but frankly I'm tying myself up in knots trying to get a solution; any help would me much appreciated!

By the way, there are about 5 thousand rows that would have additional attributes listed, from a table of about 2 million rows. I know that this denormalisation is not always desirable, but for our situation right now, it will be very helpful.

Comment: What's the problem with it as it is now?

Comment: @Ben - The problem is in the way our bits of third party software references the Id, expecting unique attributes (in the real case, this corresponds to each city having only one location. going through a denormalisation process to make an MI database and we would also expect one city to have one location. We don't care about the alternative spellings of the states in (e.g.) Saudi Arabia - any one will do for making an address of a supplier at a city. We could use `SELECT TOP 1` on every query, but seemed better to make the table efficient to use.